# Action delegate as a member doesn't compile

Tags: c#, esb

Why doesn't this code compile:

```
public class FakeESBSingleMessage<T> : IBusEnabledClass
{
    private Action<T> SubscribedAction { get; set; }

    #region IBusEnabledClass

    public void Publish<T>(T message)
    {
        SubscribedAction(message);
    }

    public void Subscribe<T>(string ID, Action<T> action)
    {
        SubscribedAction = action;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

It give the following errors:

Error   37  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'T [..FakeESBSingleMessage.cs(8)]' to 'T'   ..FakeESBSingleMessage.cs   16  30
Error   39  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Action [mscorlib.dll]' to 'System.Action [mscorlib.dll]'   ..FakeESBSingleMessage.cs   21  32
Error   36  Delegate 'System.Action' has some invalid arguments  ..\FakeESBSingleMessage.cs  16  13

I'm trying to create a fake ESB component for testing, that saves the delegate passed on Subscribe and calls it when publish is called.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You get the compile error because your Publish and Subscribe messages define a new type parameter T, rather than using the one defined in the class.  Try this instead:

```
public class FakeESBSingleMessage<T> : IBusEnabledClass
{
    private Action<T> SubscribedAction { get; set; }

    #region IBusEnabledClass

    public void Publish(T message)
    {
        SubscribedAction(message);
    }

    public void Subscribe(string ID, Action<T> action)
    {
        SubscribedAction = action;
    }

    #endregion
}
```